# Differences in JS between 'middleman server' and 'middleman build'

Tags: javascript, regex, ember.js, zurb-foundation, middleman

I'm trying to build my Middleman + Ember site through Middleman's "build" command but noticed that there is a difference in how the Javascript is being exported.  If I have it compile the JS without debugging the assets through 'middleman server', then everything is fine.  However, when the same thing is done through the 'build' command, some of the characters in a regex command that's part of Foundation get changed and are considered invalid, causing the whole site not to load.  Since I'm not exactly sure how to describe what happened to the characters, below are the two files compared in Kaleidoscope.

[Compared files http://f.cl.ly/items/0X2f0W1I2o0X371s2V3u/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-20%20at%2012.57.31%20AM.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/0X2f0W1I2o0X371s2V3u/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-20%20at%2012.57.31%20AM.png)

Why are the two files different at all?  How can I tell the build command not to do whatever it's doing?

**Edit:** Here's the error that I get in the JS console

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(https?|ftp|file|ssh):\/\/(((([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-zA-Z]|\d|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])|(([a-zA-Z]|\d|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])*([a-zA-Z]|\d|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])))\.)+(([a-zA-Z]|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])|(([a-zA-Z]|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])*([a-zA-Z]|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[î€€-ï£¿]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[Â -íŸ¿ï¤€-ï·ï·°-ï¿¯])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?/: Range out of order in character class`

**Edit 2:** [Here](https://gist.github.com/alexlafroscia/912833bf8169f6855aa8) is my config.rb (with some of the comments stripped out for concision)

**Edit 3:** [Here](http://cl.ly/TXKp) is a link to the part of the Foundation JS that Middleman seems to be having an issue with. I was able to temporarily fix my issues by including all of Foundation except for this part.

Comment: Are you using the same encoding?

Comment: Is there a way to tell Middleman to do it the same way?  I'm not sure why it wouldn't use the same encoding by default...

Comment: Can you show how the regex becomes invalid, please.

Comment: Question edited to add the JS error that I'm getting

Comment: Post up your `config.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some of the the compressing options upon build? (See http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/file-size-optimization/#toc_1 for details.)

`activate :minify_javascript` might be the cause. But as it reads ...

> If you are already using a compressed file that includes .min in its
>   filename, Middleman won't touch it. This can be good for libraries
>   like jQuery which are carefully compressed by their authors ahead of
>   time.

... you might be using a non-minified version of Foundation. Or a minified version that does not have `.min` within the filename.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help.  I tried to include the pre-minified version of Foundation, built with Middleman, and then got the same error.  Even disabling the :minify_javascript option completely still messes with the encoding in that bit of regex.  I linked to a Gist of my config.rb, maybe someone can spot something

Comment: Can you link to the Foundation JavaScript file also? So I can try myself locally to see if it also messes the encoding up on build.